# Grunt dynamic mapping configuration to output one file

Tags: gruntjs

Is it possible using the dynamic mapping configuration to output one minimized file instead of one per src file?

```
cssmin: {
  target: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'release/css',
      src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
      dest: 'css/finalfile.css',
      ext: '.min.css'
    }]
  }
}
```

This configuration creates folder named css/finalfile.css and generates one output file per one src file.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard file config to do that.

```
cssmin: {
      target: {
        files: {
            'output.css': ['app/**/*.css']
        } 
      }
   }
```

Above will minify and concatenate all the CSS files from app directory into output.css